# rails rspec email_spec fails but real emailing works

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, email-spec

Real emailing works but the test fails. Not sure whats going wrong. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

TasksController
  POST create
    with valid params
      emails the collaborators (FAILED - 1)

```
  it 'emails the collaborators' do
    post :create, { :task => valid_attributes }

    Emailer.should_receive(:send_email).with(user, :new_task, assigns(:task).project)
  end
```

Failures:

1) TasksController POST create with valid params emails the collaborators
     Failure/Error: Emailer.should_receive(:send_email).with(user, :new_task, assigns(:task).project)
       ().send_email(#, :new_task, 'blah')
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times

I have the following gems:
rails (3.2.7)
rspec-rails (2.11.4)
email_spec (1.2.1)

Comment: Even this assertion is not passing: `expect {post :create, { :task => valid_attributes }}.to change(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries, :size).by(1)`

Comment: Had to put `require 'rspec/rails/mocha'` call in spec_helper.rb at the bottom to get it working.

Comment: Removed mocha as it stopped working after i put the require 'rspec/rails/mocha' line at the bottom. So, am now happy with email_spec working with rspec mocks.